# Mysql sort - SORTING SOME BUT NOT OTHERS?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

Okay, here is my query:

```
SELECT NAME, 
       DATE_FORMAT(DATE_WRITTEN, "%c/%e/%y") AS written_date, 
       DATE_FORMAT(RETURN_DATE, "%c/%e/%y")  AS return_date 
FROM   `pfp`.`returns` AS `Re` 
       LEFT JOIN `pfp`.`insurance` AS `Insurance` 
              ON ( `insurance`.`id` = `Re`.`INSURANCE_ID` ) 
       LEFT JOIN `pfp`.`remain` AS `Remain` 
              ON ( `remain`.`id` = `Re`.`REMAIN_ID` ) 
       LEFT JOIN `pfp`.`formula` AS `Formula` 
              ON ( `formula`.`id` = `remain`.`FORMULA_ID` ) 
WHERE  `NOT_RETURNED` = 'F' 
       AND `RETURN_DATE` BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-08-22' 
ORDER  BY `RETURN_DATE` DESC 
LIMIT  100
```

The problem is that it sorts by the date 14-8-9 down to 14-8-7 then jumps back up to 14-8-22 and downward from there... why??

Comment: Because your dates are being cast as strings.  And that's how strings sort.

Comment: This is a super inefficient query. As Siyual mentioned, you need to sort on the base column, not the formatted string.

Answer (score 2):

When you sort by `return_date`, you are sorting by the formatted alias.  Instead, use the table alias to identify that you really want the column:

```
WHERE  `NOT_RETURNED` = 'F' 
       AND `RETURN_DATE` BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-08-22' 
ORDER  BY re.RETURN_DATE DESC 
LIMIT  100
```

I am guessing that it is in the `re` table.  Use the appropriate alias.

EDIT:

The fact that the column aliases are searched first is [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> MySQL resolves unqualified column or alias references in ORDER BY
>   clauses by searching in the select_expr values, then in the columns of
>   the tables in the FROM clause. For GROUP BY or HAVING clauses, it
>   searches the FROM clause before searching in the select_expr values.
>   (For GROUP BY and HAVING, this differs from the pre-MySQL 5.0 behavior
>   that used the same rules as for ORDER BY.)

I can speculate on the reasons for this (which I think is consistent with the ANSI standard).  SQL queries are *logically* processed in a particular order, something like `from`, then `where`, then `select`, then `order by` (leaving out other clauses).  This logical processing determines how the query is compiled and what identifiers mean.  The logical processing explains why column aliases are not allowed in the `where` clause -- from the perspective of the compiler, they are not yet identified.

When it comes to the `order by`, the identifier is determined from the inside out.  The first definition is the version in the `select`, so it chooses that before going to the `from`.

Comment: I'm curious on this one, the column and the alias are both return_date, how is MySql deciding which to actually use for the order by?

Comment: @Andrew . . . See the addendum to the answer.